# How to unload library (DLL) from the JVM

Tags: java, native-code

I need to unload a DLL that was loaded with `System.loadLibrary(..)`, anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I don't have any experience of this, but a bit of digging shows that the library should be unloaded when the classloader which loaded the library is garbage collected.

Links:

- [Invocation API docs (Sun) - look for "Library and Version Management"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#library_version)
- [Java JNI DLL Unloading tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20140704120535/http://www.codethesis.com/blog/unload-java-jni-dll)

Comment: I just wasted 3 hours on this: The Java JNI DLL Unloading tutorial works, but **you cannot have a finalize() method in either your CustomClassLoader or your class that contains the native method!** I did not investigate why, but my guess is that it's related to the deprecation of finalize(). When removing the finalize from the example code everything works great!