# Java release library

Tags: java, system

I am looking to load a library into Java, and then delete the file afterwards- problem is, I can't delete it while it's still in use. Any idea on how to "release" it so that the library will not be in use?

Comment: you want to delete the library contents on the disk or just the library dependency of the project?

Comment: I don't think you can. **Why** do you want to do this?

Comment: You should be able to read the file to memory, delete it and then use custom class loader to load classes from in-memory jar. This is a lot of work though. I doubt what you are trying to achieve is worth it.

Comment: Elliot- Because we don't want the library lying around afterwards
Banthar- Anything simpler?

Comment: How about [File.deleteOnExit()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit())?

Comment: By library you mean a jar file or a native library (dll)?

Comment: dll

deleteOnExit() hasn't been working

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to unload dll from java JVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453359/how-to-unload-dll-from-java-jvm) - If that's a DLL, it's even more tricky. Try [this and linked questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453359/how-to-unload-dll-from-java-jvm).